# How to know ebs device name in cloudformation template before creation of ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I'm taking reference from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-blockdevicemappings in order to create a new instance.

While creating from portal there's an option to increase the size of OS disk(root disk). And after the instance boots it generally has this mount

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1                         970G  129G  842G  14% /
```

I want to specify the size of OS disk in template but the block device attribute has `DeviceName` field

[image]

How do I know prior to the creation of vm if the `DeviceName` would be `/dev/nvme0n1p1`?
Or can it be named anything and the template will consider it as the size to give to the OS disk?

Will specifying `BlockDeviceMapping` add a new disk or expand the OS disk?

Answer (score 0):

The NVMe device names aren't stable.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html):

> In Linux, NVMe device names follow the pattern /dev/nvme<x>n<y>, where <x> is the enumeration order, and, for EBS, <y> is 1. Occasionally, devices can respond to discovery in a different order in subsequent instance starts, which causes the device name to change.

In order to map the device name returned by the attach-volume API (e.g. `/dev/sdh`) to the NVMe disk name see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70212073/1222612).

Note that `/dev/nvme0n1p1` (what you have above) is a disk partition for the `/dev/nvme0n1` disk.